# Python nornir unittest mocking how to?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using the nornir (3.3.0) automation framework with Python 3.8. I'd like to mock the SSH access to the devices in order to do testing without having some real or virtual network equipment online. How would I use patch or Mock/MagicMock from unittest.mock to mock netmiko_send_command (ssh interaction with device)?

I have the following nornir task function:

```
# dbb_automation/tasks.py

from nornir.core.task import Task, Result
from nornir_netmiko.tasks import netmiko_send_command

def get_interfaces_with_ip(task: Task):
    log.debug(f"{task.name}: Getting result on host {task.host}")
    result: MultiResult = task.run(name="show ip int br | e unass", task=netmiko_send_command,
                      command_string="show ip int br | e unass")
    
    content_str = result[0].result

    task.run(
        task=write_file,
        filename=f"outputs/{task.host}-{purpose}.{ending}",
        content=content_str
    )
    
    return Result(
        host=task.host,
        result=f"{task.host.name} got ip result"
    )
```

and the following test case (work in progress):

```
# tests/test_tasks.py

from dbb_automation.tasks import get_interfaces_with_ip
from nornir import InitNornir
from nornir.core.filter import F
from tests.settings import *

def test_get_interfaces_with_ip():
    # [x] init nornir with fake host
    # [ ] patch/mock netmiko_send_command
    # [ ] check file contents with patched return string of netmiko_send_command

    nr = InitNornir(
        core={
            "raise_on_error": True
        },
        runner={
            "plugin": "threaded",
            "options": {
                "num_workers": 1,
            }
        },
        inventory={
            "plugin": "SimpleInventory",
            "options": {
                "host_file": DNAC_HOSTS_YAML,
                "group_file": DNAC_GROUPS_YAML,
                "defaults_file": DNAC_DEFAULT_YAML
            }
        },
        logging={
            "log_file": "logs/nornir.log"
        }
    )
    result = nr.filter(F(has_parent_group="Borders")).run(name="get_interfaces_with_ip", task=get_interfaces_with_ip)
    
    # todo: test code

    assert False
```

Regards,

Gérard

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Key was to patch to where the imported function is used not to where it is defined and to set the return value on the mock object.

```
@patch("dbb_automation.tasks.netmiko_send_command")
def test_get_interfaces_with_ip(mock_netmiko_send_command, nr):
...
    mock_netmiko_send_command.return_value = """Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet22      10.1.54.146     YES TFTP   up                    up      
Loopback0              10.150.32.2     YES other  up                    up      
Port-channel1.2        10.150.33.65    YES manual up                    up 
...     
"""
```

```
import pytest
import os
import shutil
from unittest.mock import patch
from dbb_automation.tasks import get_interfaces_with_ip
from nornir import InitNornir
from nornir.core.filter import F
from tests.settings import *


@pytest.fixture()
def nr():
    nr = InitNornir(
        core={
            "raise_on_error": True
        },
        runner={
            "plugin": "threaded",
            "options": {
                "num_workers": 1,
            }
        },
        inventory={
            "plugin": "SimpleInventory",
            "options": {
                "host_file": DNAC_HOSTS_YAML,
                "group_file": DNAC_GROUPS_YAML,
                "defaults_file": DNAC_DEFAULT_YAML
            }
        },
        logging={
            "log_file": "logs/nornir.log"
        }
    )
    return nr


@patch("dbb_automation.tasks.netmiko_send_command")
def test_get_interfaces_with_ip(mock_netmiko_send_command, nr):
    output_folder_name = "outputs"
    shutil.rmtree(output_folder_name)
    os.mkdir(output_folder_name)

    mock_netmiko_send_command.return_value = """Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet22      10.1.54.146     YES TFTP   up                    up      
Loopback0              10.150.32.2     YES other  up                    up      
Port-channel1.2        10.150.33.65    YES manual up                    up      
"""
    nr.filter(F(has_parent_group="Borders")).run(name="get_interfaces_with_ip", task=get_interfaces_with_ip)
    # test code
    count = 0
    files_found = None
    for root_dir, cur_dir, files in os.walk(output_folder_name):
        count += len(files)
        assert files_found is None  # make sure there are no subdirectories
        files_found = files
    assert count == 4  # we expect a file for each host
    for file_name in files_found:
        with open(f"{output_folder_name}/{file_name}") as f:
            assert f.read() == mock_netmiko_send_command.return_value
```